# Use Powershell to determine maximum data drives allowed on an Azure VM

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I am trying to determine if there is a way to programmatically determine the maximum allowed data drives when provisioning an Azure VM.

It seems that you may add as many as you wish, only for the creation to then fail if you have added too many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Get-AzureRmVmSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619366.aspx) which will give you a list of entries such as -

> MaxDataDiskCount     : 8
>
> MemoryInMB           : 7168
>
> Name                 : Standard_A3
>
> NumberOfCores        : 4
>
> OSDiskSizeInMB       : 1047552
>
> ResourceDiskSizeInMB : 291840

So you could use something like

```
$location = "westeurope"
$Size = "Standard_A3"
((Get-AzureRmVMSize -Location $location).where({$_.name `
                -match $Size})).MaxDataDiskCount
```

Which would give

> 8